# CKEDITOR extra html tag when paste from word

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I have blog page in my website and website try to write content with CKEDITOR and copy it from word but when the content publiched, the html have too many extra tag that the are not useful.
how can we filter and delete extra tag and just save main html tag for blog page
thank you

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide any code sample, its hard to find out your problem. From my understanding I am writing this answer. Hope this will help.
When you save the text from the **CKEDITOR** fields, it saves text and HTML tags as well. So while viewing the saved texts, you can use the Laravel blade engine print function like this.

```
{!! $variale->field_name !!}
```

It will remove the HTML tags and only the text will be shown.